# Offset controls disabled when wrapping text around object in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, text-wrap

In InDesign, I have a non-anchored image (in a frame) that is linked to a Photoshop (psd) document. I selected the frame and choose "Wrap around object shape." The text correctly wraps around the object (ignoring the transparent portions of the image). I want to increase the offset on the left side of the image so the text doesn't touch the image. However, as shown below, only the top offset control is enabled. The left, right, and bottom controls are disabled (grayed). How can I change the left offset?

[image: InDesign Text Wrap Panel]

I've tried various combinations of the Wrap and Contour Options without success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you choose *Wrap around object shape* the *Top Offset* works as a uniform offset all around the object. It wouldn't really make sense to be able to set the offset for all four "sides" when the object is complex.

A thing you can do is to override the automatic offset and manually manipulate the offset with *Direct Selection Tool*. Once you have manually adjusted the offset, you can no longer set the offset in the *Text Wrap* panel. If you want to revert to automatic mode, you can select *No text wrap* and then apply *Wrap around object shape* again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I can see where left/top/right/bottom offsets could be a little strange with a round object (my object is comprised of rectangles, similar to an "T"). I decided it was cleanest to add the white "padding" to the Photoshop image and use the standard "wrap around object" selection.